# Capture orientation change event before it happens

Tags: android, layout, rotation, orientation

It's simple to lock the orientation to portrait or landscape.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

or to capture when the screen rotates:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

But how can I capture a rotation event, before it happens? I want to control what happens on my layout if the orientation changes, overriding the default behavior of actually rotating the screen. Is it possible?

Comment: ` what happens on my layout if...`. That is traditionally done by saving activity state, and then re-creating it from that state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this piece of code in onPause() method. When rotatio changes, activty re-coustructs it self which means on-Create is called again and previous activity is finish();

```
    int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
        if (display.getRotation() == Surface.ROTATION_0)
        // play with different angles e.g ROTATION_90, ROTATION_180
    }
```

So when rotation changes the previous activites's onPause() will be called and at that stage you can decide what you want with new orientation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Force the activity to stay in one mode (e.g. landscape) via `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in `onCreate(..)`
2. Attach your own orientation listener,

   orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI) {

   ```
           @Override
           public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
               if (Math.abs(orientation - 90) < 30){
                      // your device orientation has changed, you can update UI                        accordingly, (layout won't rotate).
           }
       };
       orientationEventListener.enable();
   ```

Keep in mind that if you do this you will receive x & y axis of touch events 'inversed' when you discard the configuration change. Also, if you have a navigation bar, it will remain where it is and won't rotate as well!