# Android detect orientation before the screen rotates

Tags: android, rotation

I was wondering if there is a way to detect a screen orientation change before it actually rotates. I know

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {}
```

is called after the screen rotates, but I was wondering if you can call something before the ui rotates.

I want to manually call a resize function in a webview before the screen rotates because I am experiencing a delay between when the screen rotates and when the webview browser resize function is being called.

Thanks for the help.

I saw this which I feel is close but I can't get it to detect a change on my test phone.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19242714/2657567

Comment: I think you can use onSaveInstanceState() callback..

Comment: That doesn't seem to be called when the orientation changes. Wouldn't that only happen if the activity is restated. I am suppressing that with android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize...